# Using MongoDB with stream of dictionary objects

Tags: json, mongodb, search, indexing, olap-cube

In an application, I have to store and search many semi-structured objects (100M+); each object has a number of attributes ranging from 10 to 10K, with some attributes re-occurring. Normally, once stored, the objects won't change. These objects can be seen as Python dictionaries.

The attributes are generated by users, so I can't predict what they will create. As the schema changes very often, traditional DBMSs would be quite painful to mantain, so I started to have a look at MongoDB. At first glance, it looks ideal, as I can just dump JSON objects into it and search them by criteria on attributes.

This is an example of my stream of objects in JSON:

```
{ "my_id": 1,
  "number_of_clients": 30,
  "height": 450,
  "company_code": "fhxA7"
  "name":"example"
  ...
},
{ "my_id": 2,
  "wheels": 4,
  "height": 450,
  "weight": 495,
  "type":"Car",
  "model": "TestZ6"
  ...
}, ...
```

After a while, there are thousands of different fields. On these objects, I want to run some comparisons and cluster similar objects. An example of a query could be `find all objects that have a field "weight" in range 400-450 and "height" equal to 450`.

Indeed, this works nicely on small samples. What kind of scalability issue am I likely to encounter after dumping millions of objects into MongoDB? Is it feasable to index every different field? Do you have pointers to similar cases?

If MongoDB is unfit for this scenario, what other technology would you recommend to look at (such as OLAP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except full-text index, there's no way to index all fields. In your scenario I don't think full-text applies though. My advice is:

Don't let the user decide your data structure. Even if you can store them, it would be painful to use them. You can always organize them into a small object like:

```
{
  "my_id": 1,
  fields: [{
    name: "number_of_clients",
    value: 30
  }, {
    name: "height",
    value: 450
  }, {
    name: "company_code",
    value: "fhxA7"
  }
  ...
  ]
}
```

It's not that straight forward, but then you can build index on `fields.name` and `fields.value`:

```
db.coll_name.ensureIndex({"fields.name": 1});
db.coll_name.ensureIndex({"fields.value": 1});
```

or [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) if necessary:

```
db.coll_name.ensureIndex({"fields.name": 1, "fields.value": 1});
```

And your query would be like to find:

> documents that contains 'weight'

and

> the `value` of that object is between 400 and 450

Do the query with [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

```
db.coll_name.find({
  fields: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: 'weight',
      value: {$gt: 400, $lt: 450}
    }
  }
});
```

As a trade off, you'll have to make sure there's no duplicate fields by yourself.

That's all that comes into my mind right now. Hope it helps.